# How to listen Jquery mobile event?

Tags: jquery, events, mobile

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#select-native-1 option:selected").select( function () { 
    alert("a");
    });
});
</script>
...
<form>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">
            <option id="burnabyCampus" value="1">A</option>
            <option id="downtownCampus" value="2">B</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to listen option select event from jQuery Mobile. Yet I don't know the proper way of doing it? Where can I find it?

What's wrong with mine as of now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be watching when the input changes, not when the document is ready...

```
$('#select-native-1').change(function(){
    alert('input changed');
});
```

see fiddle  -- https://jsfiddle.net/6L08nj2u/11/

edit: you should still have your jquery wrapped in a 'ready' but bind this function to the 'change' of your input. So if that is all your js,

```
$(document).ready(function() {    // wrap everything in ready
    $('#select-native-1').change(function(){
        alert('input changed');
    });
});
```

so now if you want to get the *text* value before it changes, let's put it inside the ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    // wrap everything in ready
// page is loaded

// what the value is as soon as page is done loading
$('#select-native-1 option:selected').text();


// watch for every time the value changes
        $('#select-native-1').change(function(){
            alert('input changed');
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you. One thing I din't mention was that jQuery Mobile basic select by default has first option selected - or at least it seems. Can you listen select event as page load? (default select)

Comment: And is there api doc for change()?? Can't find

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/ , and i never said we're watching the text change - in the past update i showed you how to select the text because without that and trying to access it via .val() would give you 1,2,3 etc. , look at the code, we are selecting your input and binding that to 'change'